# Firewall Ports for Inter-domain Connectivity

Tags: active-directory

I am trying to design an environment that has one forest with an empty root, a user domain and multiple domains for different groups that have firewalls between the domains.  I want to have a central user database but segmentation at the IP level for each group of folks.    For the first group the forest would look like this

[image]

I will be adding other groups' domains after this first one is working.

Assume there is a firewall between each domain and they are segmented with a subnet for each group's domain.

Here is the initial firewall design

[image]

I am trying to allow a user on the Application server to enumerate the users and group objects in the users domain.   Here is the problem.    My users can log in no problem if I don't allow any connectivity between the app server and the User DCs but they cannot enumerate users and groups.    Other the other hand If I allow TCP 389 (LDAP) and TCP 88 (Kerberos) I can enumerate the users and groups but interactive logins are really slow and the app server is looking for 135 (EPmapper) to be open during profile load.    As a test I opened 135 and then the EPmapper passed a random high for the netlogon port which of course the app server then tries to hit.

So what do you think is best course of action?    I cannot open all random highs, that is silly.   I can make the netlogon port static on all my DCs and then open only that port.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you [need](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179442).

Comment: I think your post got lost somewhere

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean ...

Comment: The link for the MS article was not there last night.   The word need was just text.  Now it is good.

Comment: So after reading that, the article looks like it is DC to DC based communication which is currently working fine.   I am looking more for advice on the best course of action.  How to do it is clear in the MS docs.  I just have at least two choices and am looking for the pros and cons of each.    My focus is on the app server that is not a DC.   How should it communicate to the DC in the remote domain?

Comment: Is there a chance to configure VPN between locations?

Comment: None of this crosses the internet, I control all of the space.   They just have a requirement to have IP separation between the groups.

Comment: Check the REFERENCES section in the following article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839880 espessially http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154596